# Force the write database connection on Laravel relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using separate `read` and `write` connections in my Laravel app:

```
'mysql' => [
            'write' => ['host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE', 'localhost'),],
            'read'  => ['host' => env('DB_HOST_READ', 'localhost'),],
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'very'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'secret'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Normally, if I'd like to force the `write` connection to be used, I'd write:

```
$user = User::onWriteConnection()->where('email', 'test@example.com')->first();
```

This works just fine, directly on a model. But what if I have a case where I need to use the `write` connection throughout one specific method which uses relations, like this:

```
$user = User::find(123);

$user->universities()->attach(array(34, 56, 2));
$user->universities()->dettach(array(4, 78));

$primary = $user->universities()->where('primary', 1)->first();

// and so on...
```

I'd like **all** those relation-based operations (regardless whether they are, in fact, read or write ones) to be done on the `write` connection.

How do I do this in Laravel?

**What I tried:**

(1) Using the `onWriteConnection()` method on the relations - doesn't work due to the fact the [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_onWriteConnection) is static and directly connected to the Eloquent Model object.

(2) Using the `setConnection()` method:

```
$user = User::find(123);
$user->setConnection('mysql.write');
```

which throws the error that the `driver` index is not specified for the connection - which makes sense and proves it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't it automatically use the read connection for SELECT and the write connection for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE?

Comment: Yes, it does. Yet, there are cases where I need to force the connection. It's related to the fact that using separate DB hosts may lead to a problem, where the `read` does not know what the `write` just, well, wrote, if all is happening during single request.

Comment: Have you tried using it on the relation the same way you're using it on the model? The method `onWriteConnection` just sets a flag in the query builder and returns you a new instance of it, which you could use to call the relation methods.

Comment: I tried it, but `onWriteConnection` is a static Eloquent Model method. It doesn't work in the context of relation like the ones shown in my code above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could directly use the `useWritePdo()` method of the query builder, which `onWriteConnection()` calls behind the scene:

```
$primary = $user->universities()->useWritePdo()->where('primary', 1)->first();
```

Comment: You can do the opposite way by using `$query->useWritePdo = false`